# Can we do an operation(logic inside 2nd for loop of a nested for loop) involving two threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

In an interview i was asked to print composite nos b/w 1 to 100. I did it...

```
int count=0;
for(int i=3;i<=100;i++)
{
    for(int j=2;j<i;j++){
        if(i%j==0)
        count=count+1;
    }
    if(count>0)
        System.out.println(i);
    count=0;
}
```

Then she asked me to do it using two threads. As I know run() can't take arguments and we don't use two threads for atomic operation.
Is it possible to use two threads for this operation?

Based on Jigar's suggestion i wrote it like this.

```
    public class Comp extends Thread{
        int start,last;
        public Comp(int start,int last){
            this.start=start;
            this.last=last;
        }
        public void run(){
            int count=0;
            for(int i=start;i<=last;i++){
                for(int j=i-1;j>=2;j--){
                    if(i%j==0)
                        count=count+1;
                }
                if(count>0)
                    System.out.println(i);
                count=0;
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Comp c1=new Comp(3,50);
            Comp c2=new Comp(51,100);
            c1.start();
try{c1.join();}catch(Exception e){}
            c2.start();

        }
    }
```

Is it correct way of doing it to get the numbers in sequence?

Comment: `run()` can't take arguments, but any class implementing `Runnable` certainly can via its constructor ...

Comment: Actually  she tricked you. `main()` itself is a thread. Only thing you need to do is put this code in a `run()` method thats it. Now you got two threads `main()` and `run()`,

Comment: Quite frankly, this is a simple problem to parallelize. Answering this question would basically be writing a mutli-threading basic tutorial. Fire up a `ThreadPoolExecutor`, throw it two tasks, one that handles 1-50, the other handles 51-100. they can both output to a concurrent queue, sort at end, output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decompose the problem by number of threads.  For instance, assign the first thread to print out the first 1/2 of numbers and the second thread to do the other half.

```
class CompositeCounter implements Runnable{
 final int start,end;
 public CompositeCounter(int s, int e){
     start = s;
     end = e;
 }
 public void run(){
   int count=0;
   for(int i=start;i<=end;i++)
     {
       for(int j=2;j<i;j++){
          if(i%j==0)
            count=count+1;
    }
    if(count>0)
        System.out.println(i);
    count=0;
  }
}
Thread first = new Thread(new CompositeCounter(3,50);
Thread second = new Thread(new CompositeCounter(51,100);
first.start();
second.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

in your code following condition is a *bug*

```
if(count>0)
           System.out.println(i);
```

You might need a `boolean` flag to detect current number is a composite or not

You could divide range for example 3-50, 51-99 and supply it to 2 threads

Comment: I am not able to understand why it's a bug? Could you please explain... It's working properly..

Comment: consider you are at 4, it will make counter from 0 to 1, now you are at 5 which isn't a composite number but with your condition it will still print that number

Comment: When we will be at 5, then we would have executed the the statement count =0;

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be like this with the Blocking Queue:

```
public class CompositCodeTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BlockingQueue< Integer> que = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(5);
    Thread th1 = new Thread(new PrintThread(que));
    Thread th2 = new Thread(new TestCompositeThread(que));
    th1.start();
    th2.start();
}
```

}

```
class PrintThread implements Runnable{

private BlockingQueue< Integer> que ;

public PrintThread(BlockingQueue<Integer> que) {
    super();
    this.que = que;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    boolean start = true;
    while(start){
        int no = 0;
        try {
            no = que.take();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(no != 1){
            System.out.println(no);
        } else {
            start = false;
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
class TestCompositeThread implements Runnable{
```

private BlockingQueue< Integer> que ;

```
public TestCompositeThread(BlockingQueue<Integer> que) {
    super();
    this.que = que;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    for(int i = 3 ; i < 100 ; i++){
        for(int j = 2 ; j < i ; j++){
            if((i % j) == 0){
                try {
                    System.out.println("ADDED ELEMENT: " + i);
                    que.put(i);
                    break;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    try {
        que.put(1);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You already have working answers but assuming you were using Java 7 a fork/join would run this computation nicely. And with a fork/join you could very easy extend the work to as many threads you'd like.

First of you don't have to test divide all numbers up to n-1, I understand to the fullest that this is something you don't have in mind when you are in the middle of the heat. Been there, so to speak...
I would have solved the problem with a [Naive primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test), if the number is a prime it's not a composite. Values needed for this is test is division by 2 (unless the test number is 2) and all odd numbers from 3 to the square root of the test number:

```
int n = 49;

if (n % 2 == 0 && n != 2) {
    System.out.println("composite");
} else {
    for (int m = 3; m <= Math.sqrt(n); m = m + 2) {
        if (n % m == 0) {
            System.out.println("composite");
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

This test would print *composite* on standard out. Now lets extend this with a loop like you did in the first test, but we'll add all composites in a list (for a reason):

```
private List<Integer> compute(int start, int end) {
    System.out.println("Computation started");
    ArrayList<Integer> compositeList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int n = start; n <= end; n++) {
        if (n % 2 == 0 && n != 2) {
            compositeList.add(n);
        } else {
            for (int m = 3; m <= Math.sqrt(n); m = m + 2) {
                if (n % m == 0) {
                    compositeList.add(n);
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

    }

    return compositeList;
}
```

This is more or less what's needed to run a fork/join for the task. We need a ForkJoinPool and tell the pool to run the tasks. To make this happen the compute method must be in one of the fork/join worker implementations and a class implementing RecursiveTask is perfect:

```
class CompositeFinder extends RecursiveTask<List<Integer>> {

    private int start;
    private int end;

    public CompositeFinder(Integer start, Integer end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Integer> compute() {
        System.out.println("Computation started");
        ArrayList<Integer> compositeList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int n = start; n <= end; n++) {
            if (n % 2 == 0 && n != 2) {
                compositeList.add(n);
            } else {
                for (int m = 3; m <= Math.sqrt(n); m = m + 2) {
                    if (n % m == 0) {
                        compositeList.add(n);
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }

        }

        return compositeList;
    }

}
```

This is a complete forkable worker class that will make a partial computation for us. To statically start two threads for this test, lets make a main class:

```
public class CompositePoolTest {

    ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CompositePoolTest().compute();
    }

    public void compute() {

        CompositeFinder firstFinder = new CompositeFinder(1, 50);
        CompositeFinder secondFinder = new CompositeFinder(51, 100);

        forkJoinPool.invoke(firstFinder);
        forkJoinPool.invoke(secondFinder);
        List<Integer> list = firstFinder.join();
        list.addAll(secondFinder.join());
        Collections.sort(list);
        System.out.println(list);

    }
```

This will output:

```
Computation started
Computation started
[4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 30, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 38, 39, 40, 42, 44, 45, 46, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 60, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 68, 69, 70, 72, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 80, 81, 82, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 98, 99, 100]
```

The compute() method creates two forkables and starts them (invoke). When they are ready they will join in again and give us the result, which is merged and sorted.
This maybe looks like a lot of code for a little test, but when you've got your head around the fork/join framework it's a joy coding with it! The big picture is, make a forkable class that can make a slice of the work and fork them, let them join back when ready and continue with the rest.

The fork/join framework is really powerful and this test can be divided in as many threads as needed, or decided automatically by the program. This is a classical example of fork/join and you'll find it on many pages on the Internet, [this is one of them](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.gr/2012/08/java-7-forkjoin-framework-example.html). What we do is giving a threshold value for the slicing (THRESHOLD = 10), if the chunk of numbers in a fork is big enough it can be sliced in two and yet another fork is made. By doing it this way the tasks are sliced into a number of forks taking care of a given amount of numbers in a dynamic range of threads. Here's a complete example of the same test but automatically sliced into forks:

```
public class CompositePoolTest {

    ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
          new CompositePoolTest().dynamicCompute();
    }

    public void dynamicCompute() {
       DynamicCompositeFinder dynamicFinder = new DynamicCompositeFinder(1,
               100);
       forkJoinPool.invoke(dynamicFinder);
       List<Integer> list = dynamicFinder.join();
       Collections.sort(list);
       System.out.println(list);
    }
}

public class DynamicCompositeFinder extends RecursiveTask<List<Integer>> {

    private static int THRESHOLD = 10;
    private int start;
    private int end;

    public DynamicCompositeFinder(Integer start, Integer end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    protected List<Integer> compute() {
        int midValue = (end - start) / 2;
        if (midValue > THRESHOLD) {
            DynamicCompositeFinder firstHalfFinder = new DynamicCompositeFinder(
                    start, start + midValue);
            firstHalfFinder.fork();
            List<Integer> partialList = new DynamicCompositeFinder(start
                    + midValue + 1, end).compute();
            partialList.addAll(firstHalfFinder.join());
            return partialList;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Computation started for " + start + " to " + end);
            ArrayList<Integer> compositeList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int n = start; n <= end; n++) {
                if (n % 2 == 0 && n != 2) {
                    compositeList.add(n);
                } else {
                    for (int m = 3; m <= Math.sqrt(n); m = m + 2) {
                        if (n % m == 0) {
                            compositeList.add(n);
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                }

            }

            return compositeList;
        }

    }

}
```

The compute() method is first checking if the [numbers left]/2 is a larger value than the threshold and in that case the numbers are splitted into two forks, which then recursively will do the same if needed. Each split is waiting for the "real" compute to happen and will then merge the results upwards again when ready.
When running this we will get following output:

```
Computation started for 64 to 75
Computation started for 14 to 25
Computation started for 39 to 50
Computation started for 51 to 63
Computation started for 89 to 100
Computation started for 76 to 88
Computation started for 26 to 38
Computation started for 1 to 13
[4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 30, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 38, 39, 40, 42, 44, 45, 46, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 60, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 68, 69, 70, 72, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 80, 81, 82, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 98, 99, 100]
```